# Android Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have just developed a new `Android` app for my company.

On the home page of the app we would like to display a number of our companies latest Facebook posts.

When send the request to the API i am receiving the error

`"message": "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/"`

I have looked into this extensively and understand it is due to Facebook upgrading their APIs due to the recent data breach.

Within the app i have successfully implemented the Facebook Login API and can retrieve a new access token for the user.

I have generated all the necessary hash keys for the android app and have set it all up correctly on the facebook developer console.

I can achieve the functionality i require by getting the Access token from the Facebook developers Graph API Explorer however, this is not a good implementation as it is linked to my Facebook account and also only lasts for an hour.

The Facebook API states that public pages can be accessible using any user access token.

Is there currently anyway at all to use a user access token generated from the user login to retrieve a Facebook page data.

the only data i wish to retrieve is; the message, the time created and the image.

Is this possible with the current state of the Graph API or is it just a waiting game to see what Facebook will do next in the coming weeks?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-4

Comment: It is to my understanding that the page access token is only to carry out administrative tasks: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: i do not require functionality of an admin, i literally just want to pull in the post information of the page; the message, the time created and the image.

Comment: Then your understanding is fundamentally wrong to begin with, but in this instance that doesn’t matter much, because the note on top of that section is the important part here anyway.

Comment: which part do you refer to? i have read this page multiple times

Comment: The part saying all apps wanting access to this must undergo app review.